# Repeating a Table in Columns in RDLC

Tags: c#, winforms, report, rdlc

I have a Table in a VS2010 RDLC report.  It prints data out as you would print a receipt because we are trying to save some space.

I want to have the table repeat as a second column on the same page before it starts a new page.  For example:

```
Table            Table
Table            Table
Table            Table
Table            Table
Table            Table
=== page break =====
```

Instead of

```
Table
Table
Table
Table
Table
Table
Table
====page break=====
Table
Table
Table
```

How can I get a second column into the table?

Comment: I just found the Report property of Number of Columns and have changed that to 2.  Printed another Report and nothing yet.  Still monkeying around

Answer (score 0):

Under the Report properties there is a Property for Columns.
I have changed this to two(2).
But the default report viewer will not show the columns, nor will they print the columns.

So I exported the report to a PDF and then printed that file.

```
private void Export(LocalReport report)
{
        try
        {
            string deviceInfo =
              @"<DeviceInfo>
            <OutputFormat>PDF</OutputFormat>
            <PageWidth>8.5in</PageWidth>
            <PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>
            <MarginTop>0.25in</MarginTop>
            <MarginLeft>0.25in</MarginLeft>
            <MarginRight>0.25in</MarginRight>
            <MarginBottom>0.25in</MarginBottom>
            </DeviceInfo>";
            Warning[] warnings;
             string[] streamIds;
            string mimeType = string.Empty;
            string encoding = string.Empty;
            string extension = string.Empty;

            m_streams = new List<Stream>();
            byte[] bytes = report.Render("PDF", deviceInfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamIds, out warnings);

            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("output.pdf", FileMode.Create))
            {
                fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }

            foreach (Stream stream in m_streams)
                stream.Position = 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Common.LogManager.WriteToLog(ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```

and then to print i use the print dos command in a new process:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.UseShellExecute = true;
psi.Verb = "print";
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
psi.FileName = "output.pdf";
Process.Start(psi);
```

The report printed exactly as I needed it to.